# Wireless earphones connection

Tags: mac

I accidentally deleted my bluetooth speakers from my macbooks devices list. Now it will not show up again. How can I get it to show up again so I can reconnect it?

Comment: Have you tried the manufacturer's directions for reconnecting the speakers?

Comment: What kind of Bluetooth speaker do you have? Please provide brand and model number.

Comment: Mumuso 06. It's not a very common brand, but it works pretty much the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Hold the bluetooth pairing button on your bluetooth speakers for about 3-5 seconds (typically until some audible cue is played). Then you should be able to pair it with your MacBook again in bluetooth preferences.